# Consolidate differently structured arrays into one without rearranging keys or values

Tags: php

I have a page that has 4 widgets each getting data from the database. Each widgets gets data in different formats since i have a table widget, a statistics widget and a widget with just one value.

Supposing i have the results of queries returning data say in this format

```
$arr1 = array(1, 3, 5);
$arr2 = array(2, 4, 6);

$test1 = array( 
'11' => '11',
'22' => '22',
'33' => '33',
'44' => '44'
);

$array1 = array(0 => 'zero_a', 2 => 'two_a', 3 => 'three_a');
$array2 = array(1 => 'one_b', 3 => 'three_b', 4 => 'four_b');
```

how can i pass the arrays as json encoded as one but retains their array structure on the client side for easier and faster creating on widget views?.

I have looked at array_merge and according to the docs, that's not what i am looking for.

Comment: I don't really see the problem of having multiple arrays, keeps it clean imo. What you want is having a multdimensional array like in the answer. Build one array with the arrays inside and then json encode all at once. You really think that saves time client side?

Comment: Actually, i was think of json encoding them then combine the json into one big object and decode this on the client side. That i think saves me time.

Comment: Ok, yeah I think the confusion is here about the array parts. In PHP everything is an array. Having an object in javascript is way faster indeed, so could save time with large amounts of data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can i pass the arrays as json encoded as one but retains their array structure on the client side for easier and faster creating on widget views?.

You might arrange each array to be json encoded together like so:

```
$bundle = json_encode([$arr1, $arr2, $test1, $array1, $array2]);
```

Result:

```
[[1,3,5],[2,4,6],{"11":"11","22":"22","33":"33","44":"44"},{"0":"zero_a","2":"two_a","3":"three_a"},{"1":"one_b","3":"three_b","4":"four_b"}]
```

Comment: Does this attempt to merge similar keys?

Comment: No, everything remain mirror copies of the originals.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your issue correctly, you can assign your arrays to a multidimensional array.

Based in your example:

```
$dataArray = [];

$arr1 = array(1, 3, 5);
$arr2 = array(2, 4, 6);
$dataArray['data_type_one'][] = $arr1;
$dataArray['data_type_one'][] = $arr2;

$test1 = array( 
'11' => '11',
'22' => '22',
'33' => '33',
'44' => '44'
);
$dataArray['data_type_two'] = $test;

$array1 = array(0 => 'zero_a', 2 => 'two_a', 3 => 'three_a');
$array2 = array(1 => 'one_b', 3 => 'three_b', 4 => 'four_b');
$dataArray['data_type_three'][] = $array1;
$dataArray['data_type_three'][] = $array2;
```

You will end up with this array structure:

```
Array
(
    [data_type_one] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 3
                    [2] => 5
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2
                    [1] => 4
                    [2] => 6
                )
        )
    [data_type_two] => Array
        (
            [11] => 11
            [22] => 22
            [33] => 33
            [44] => 44
        )
    [data_type_three] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => zero_a
                    [2] => two_a
                    [3] => three_a
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [1] => one_b
                    [3] => three_b
                    [4] => four_b
                )
        )
)
```

Then, in your views, you can do whatever you need:

```
foreach ($arrayData['data_type_one'] as $someData) {
    echo $someData[0] . ' ';
    //will print 1 2
}

echo $dataArray['data_type_two']['11'];
//will print 11
```

Comment: Correct answer, but I don't know if it is going to get cleaner having this nested array structure.